# update_post_meta not working for save_post_{post-type}

Tags: wordpress

I try to take some data from one custom field to another in the save_post hook. First I tried the `save_post_{post-type}` hook, but `update_post_meta` is not saving anything. I then tried only save_post and it is working...
Strangely the `save_post_{post-type}` hook is fired, because it gives me some output when I dump the `$_Request` (for example). Only the update_post_meta isn't working. (And I tried this right before update_post_meta and after to make sure the google maps coordinate thingy is working, and they are, cause I also am able to dump them.)

```
add_action('save_post_listing', 'geocode_address', 999999);
function geocode_address($post_id) {
        global $api_key;

            $custom_fields = get_post_meta($post_id, '', true);
            if(!empty($custom_fields["wpcf-geo_map"][0])) {
                $resp = wp_remote_get( "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=".$api_key."&address=".urlencode($custom_fields["wpcf-geo_map"][0])."&sensor=false" );
                if ( 200 == $resp['response']['code'] ) {
                    $body = $resp['body'];
                    $data = json_decode($body);
                    if($data->status=="OK"){
                        $latitude = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
                        $longitude = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

                        update_post_meta($post_id, "wpcf-latitude", $latitude);
                        update_post_meta($post_id, "wpcf-longitude", $longitude);

                    } 
                } 

            }

}
```

Comment: What you see when you type echo $post_id.'_'.$latitude;  just before the line " update_post_meta($post_id, "wpcf-latitude", $latitude); " ?

Comment: or the status is not "OK" or there is an error with your param ... do a 
`var_dump( update_post_meta( $post_id, "wpcf-latitude", $latitude )  );`

Comment: No I get the right long and lat and also the right ID. Just the update function is not working when i am in save_post_POSTTYPE hook - it is working properly when i only use the save_post hook. That's bit strange :D

Also i just tried `var_dump( update_post_meta( $post_id, "wpcf-latitude", $latitude ) );` in both hooks but in none of them it prints out something (but `var_dump($_REQUEST)` does!)

Comment: I am facing the same issue; looking for the solution ..

Comment: Same issue here: `update_post_meta` does work inside `save_post`, but not within `save_post_[post_type]`.